# how to insert query using mysql c++ connector

Tags: c++, mysql, mysql-connector, omnet++

I need to insert my simulation result into database.I am using mysql c++ connector in ubuntu and omnet++.The last row is highlighted.What is the problem in here?

```
                        sql::Driver *driver;
                        sql::Connection *con;
                        sql::Statement *stmt;
                        sql::ResultSet *res;

                        driver = get_driver_instance();
                             con = driver->connect("TCP://127.0.0.1:3306", "root", "963369");

                             con->setSchema("db_teste_omnet");
                             stmt = con->createStatement();

                        ev << "Inserting into DB \n";
                        res->executeQuery("insert into omnetpp.sensor1 (dateTime, readings) values ('1', '2')");
```

Comment: Open up the command line version of MySql.  Execute your query using the command line window.  What errors are reported?  Please **edit** your post with errors.

Answer (score 0):

`res->executeQuery`

You can't execute a query on a result set.

try this instead:

`res = stmt->executeQuery(....)`

... and for goodness sake store your statement, connection and result set pointers in unique_ptrs...

Comment: You're right, but not completely. Since this is an INSERT, `executeUpdate()` needs to be used instead of `executeQuery()`. So: `int affected_rows=stmt->executeUpdate(...);`.